# Change Content Type for all sub sites and lists/libraries

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, content-type-hub, libraries, hub-site

We are using 2016 On Prem

For our site collection an admin user can do the following

1. Create Sub Sites
2. Create Document Libraries

For any of these items we use custom content types to enforce metadata that is required to be filled in before they can check in anything

What we would like to do only change the content type for them every time they create a new library or a list without any full trust code

Something like Hub Content Types, however in classic mode on 2016 On Prem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you would create a template for the use when creating site. You don't have to create a new Document Library, simply add the Content Type with metadata, and remove the default "document" CT.

Then you save the site as a template for later use. When you create a new site you make use of your template, and there is no need for the extra work switching CTs every time a new site is created.

More to read: [Create a SharePoint Site Collection with a custom Template using Powershell](https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2012/06/create-a-sharepoint-site-collection-with-a-custom-template-using-powershell.html)

Comment: Thanks Benny. This would work